# SPSC thread safe with fences

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, c11, atomic

I just want my code as simple as possible and thread safe.

**With C11 atomics**

Regarding part "7.17.4 Fences" of the ISO/IEC 9899/201X draft

> X and Y , both operating on some atomic object M, such that A is
>   sequenced before X, X modifies M, Y is sequenced before B, and Y reads
>   the value written by X or a value written by any side effect in the
>   hypothetical release sequence X would head if it were a release
>   operation.

Is this code thread safe (with "w_i" as "object M") ?
Are "w_i" and "r_i" need both to be declared as _Atomic ?
If only w_i is _Atomic, can the main thread keep an old value of r_i in cache and consider the queue as not full (while it's full) and write data ?
What's going on if I read an atomic without atomic_load ?

I have made some tests but all of my attempts seems to give the right results.
However, I know that my tests are not really correct regarding multithread : I run my program several times and look at the result.

Even if neither w_i not r_i are declared as _Atomic, my program work, but only fences are not sufficient regarding C11 standard, right ?

```
typedef int rbuff_data_t;

struct rbuf {
    rbuff_data_t * buf;
    unsigned int bufmask;

    _Atomic unsigned int w_i;
    _Atomic unsigned int r_i;
};
typedef struct rbuf rbuf_t;

static inline int
thrd_tryenq(struct rbuf * queue, rbuff_data_t val) {
    size_t next_w_i;

    next_w_i = (queue->w_i + 1) & queue->bufmask;

    /* if ring full */
    if (atomic_load(&queue->r_i) == next_w_i) {
        return 1;
    }

    queue->buf[queue->w_i] = val;
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
    atomic_store(&queue->w_i, next_w_i);

    return 0;
}

static inline int
thrd_trydeq(struct rbuf * queue, rbuff_data_t * val) {
    size_t next_r_i;

    /*if ring empty*/
    if (queue->r_i == atomic_load(&queue->w_i)) {
        return 1;
    }
    next_r_i = (queue->r_i + 1) & queue->bufmask;
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
    *val = queue->buf[queue->r_i];
    atomic_store(&queue->r_i, next_r_i);
    return 0;
}
```

I call theses functions as follow :
Main thread enqueue some data :

```
while (thrd_tryenq(thrd_get_queue(&tinfo[tnum]), i)) {
    usleep(10);
    continue;
}
```

Others threads dequeue data :

```
static void *
thrd_work(void *arg) {
    struct thrd_info *tinfo = arg;
    int elt;

    atomic_init(&tinfo->alive, true);

    /* busy waiting when queue empty */
    while (atomic_load(&tinfo->alive)) {
        if (thrd_trydeq(&tinfo->queue, &elt)) {
            sched_yield();
            continue;
        }
        printf("Thread %zu deq %d\n",
                tinfo->thrd_num, elt);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**With asm fences**

Regarding a specific platform x86 with lfence and sfence,
If I remove all C11 code and just replace fences by

```
asm volatile ("sfence" ::: "memory");
```

and

```
asm volatile ("lfence" ::: "memory");
```

(My understanding of these macro is : compiler fence to prevent memory access to be reoganized/optimized + hardware fence)

do my variables need to be declared as volatile for instance ?

I have already seen this ring buffer code above with only these asm fences but with no atomic types and I was really surprised, I want to know if this code was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reply regarding C11 atomics, platform specifics are too complicated and should be phased out.

Synchronization between threads in C11 is only guaranteed through some system calls (e.g for `mtx_t`) and atomics. Don't even try to do it without.

That said, sychronization works *via* atomics, that is visibility of side effects is guaranteed to propagate via the visibility of effects on atomics. E.g for the simplest consistency model, sequential, whenever thread T2 sees a modification thread T1 has effected on an atomic variable A, all side effects before that modication in thread T1 are visible to T2.

So not all your shared variables need to be atomic, you only must ensure that your state is properly propagated via an atomic. In that sense fences buy you nothing when you use sequential or acquire-release consistency, they only complicate the picture.

Some more general remarks:

- Since you seem to use the sequential consistency model, which is the
  default, the functional writing of atomic operations (e.g
  `atomic_load`) is superfluous. Just evaluating the atomic variable is
  exactly the same.
- I have the impression that you are attempting optimization much too
  early in your development. I think you should do an implementation
  for which you can prove correctness, first. Then, **if and only if**
  you notice a performance problem, you should start to think about
  optimization. It is very unlikely that such an atomic data structure
  is a real bottleneck for your applcation. You'd have to have a very
  large number of threads that all simultaneously hammer on your poor
  little atomic variable, to see a measurable bottleneck here.

Comment: Thank you! If I avoid fences, I have to use atomic_store_explicit with the memory order wanted ? Or I just would write : queue->w_i = next_w_i (it's the relaxed order used by default ? )
In which case should I use fences ?

Comment: No, the default order is sequential consistency, the strongest possible.